# Adding value on multiple EditText and getting the Total on every textchange

Tags: java, android

How can I sum all the total of my multiple `EditText` without using a `Button` but only on TextWatcher's `onTextChanged()` method. assuming this is my layout:

> EditText1 = 5
>
> EditText2 = 5
>
> EditText3 = 5
>
> EditText4 = 5
>
> Total = 20

and so on

and getting the total of it?. the total should be **CHANGING** when the `EditText`'s value is changing.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42622845/multiple-edittext-with-only-one-textwatchers-for-calculation-in-android) answer. but I can't execute it well on my program.

This is my Layout of it

[image]

Comment: what is the error? post the code you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a **`TextWatcher()`**

instead of using 5 `TextWatcher()` you can manage it using only a single `TextWatcher()`

Try this

Using below answer if all your 4 four `edittext` is not empty then it will calculate the sum of `editext` value

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    EditText edtOne, edtTwo, edtThree, edtFour;
    TextView tvResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edtOne = findViewById(R.id.edtOne);
        edtTwo = findViewById(R.id.edtTwo);
        edtThree = findViewById(R.id.edtThree);
        edtFour = findViewById(R.id.edtFour);

        tvResult = findViewById(R.id.tvResult);

        edtOne.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
        edtTwo.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
        edtThree.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
        edtFour.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

    }

    TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(edtOne.getText().toString().trim())
                    || !TextUtils.isEmpty(edtTwo.getText().toString().trim())
                    || !TextUtils.isEmpty(edtThree.getText().toString().trim())
                    || !TextUtils.isEmpty(edtFour.getText().toString().trim())
                    ) {


                int answer = Integer.parseInt(edtOne.getText().toString().trim()) +
                        Integer.parseInt(edtTwo.getText().toString().trim()) +
                        Integer.parseInt(edtThree.getText().toString().trim()) +
                        Integer.parseInt(edtFour.getText().toString().trim());

                Log.e("RESULT", String.valueOf(answer));
                tvResult.setText(String.valueOf(answer));
            }else {
            tvResult.setText("");
        }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    };

}
```

### UPDATE

if  you want to calculate value of all `editext` evenif your editext is empty than try below **`TextWatcher()`**

```
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(edtOne.getText().toString().trim())
                || !TextUtils.isEmpty(edtTwo.getText().toString().trim())
                || !TextUtils.isEmpty(edtThree.getText().toString().trim())
                || !TextUtils.isEmpty(edtFour.getText().toString().trim())
                ) {


            int firtValue = TextUtils.isEmpty(edtOne.getText().toString().trim()) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(edtOne.getText().toString().trim());
            int secondValue = TextUtils.isEmpty(edtTwo.getText().toString().trim()) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(edtTwo.getText().toString().trim());
            int thirdValue = TextUtils.isEmpty(edtThree.getText().toString().trim()) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(edtThree.getText().toString().trim());
            int forthValue = TextUtils.isEmpty(edtFour.getText().toString().trim()) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(edtFour.getText().toString().trim());

            int answer = firtValue + secondValue + thirdValue + forthValue;

            Log.e("RESULT", String.valueOf(answer));
            tvResult.setText(String.valueOf(answer));
        }else {
            tvResult.setText("");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to tell you how to do it, but I won't post the solution as a total code.

First of all, define integers that is the amount of your edit text count. If there is 4 edit texts, define 4 integers with like `int first = 0, second = 0, third = 0, fourth = 0;`

Then, add **separate text watchers** to your edit texts, and on your `afterTextChanged` methods, get the integer value from the string by using `Integer.parseInt(Editable s.getText.toString())` and make sure the input is convertable, otherwise you will get a `NumberFormatException`. Then, assign this value to the related edit text, for example on your first edit text use `first = Integer.parse(s.getText().toString())`.

Create a function that uses these variables to display on a textview. For instance:

```
private void showResult() {
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(first + second + third + fourth));
}
```

Then, at **every afterTextChanged methods** call this function to display the total amount.